# How to use intel pin tools on applications?

Tags: c++, intel-pin

I am trying to execute pin tools on my own executables. I am asked to use cache simulator (allcache) in order to collect miss rates.

I'm struggling with the parameters and I faced with a lot of errors actually.

The operating system is Win10-64 Bit but I'm using CygWin.

Currently I am trying to trigger it with pin.exe which is under intel64/bin folder.

`$ pin.exe -t allcache.cpp -- myOwnThingy.exe`

But I'm getting this error:

> E: Failure to open DLL file C:\cygwin64\home\blabla\pin-3.7-97619-g0d0c92f4f-msvc-windows\intel64\bin\allcache.cpp

Why does it need to open a `dll` file especially when there are only .cpps and header files in the examples?

Comment: What instructions told you to use that command line to start `pin`?

Answer (score 1):

Pin tools must be compiled to be used. You can't run the source files. Use 'make' to build the pintool.